# Shared memory exercise, consumer not receives data

Tags: c, process, shared-memory

Basically my exercise is to create a shared memory between two processes, one is the producer and the other one is the consumer,

producer has to generate letters and consumer has to print it, right now i have this (but the issue is the code is not printing)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int segmento;
    int n1 = fork();
    int n2 = fork();
    int i;
    char *buffer;
    char alphabet[26];

    segmento = shmget (IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof (char) * 32, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    buffer = (char *) shmat (segmento, 0, 0);

    for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++){
        alphabet[k] = 65 + k;
    }
    // child process because return value zero
    for(i = 0; i < 128; i++){
        if (n1 == 0 && n2 > 0){
            int index = i % 32;
            int r = rand() % 26;
            buffer[index] = alphabet[r];
        }
        if (n2 == 0 && n1 > 0){
            printf("%c",buffer[0]);
        }

    }   
    return 0;
}
```

I have already tried to change the shared memory values, but im stuck

Comment: `int n1 = fork(); int n2 = fork();` That is not good code. After the first `fork` both the parent and the child will also then run the second `fork`. So you are ending up with 3 processes and not 2. Also, you are not doing any error checking such as on the `shmget` and `shmat` calls which makes the code fragile and difficult to debug.

Comment: Side note: you don't need the `alphabet` array. Just use `buffer[index] = 'A' + r`